# Discerning a pattern from integers coprime to some m.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is a question from *A Friendly Introduction to Number Theory* by Joseph Silverman.

Let $m$ be some positive integer, and let $a_1, ... , a_{\phi(m)}$ be the integers between 1 and m that are relatively prime to $m$.
Write the quantity ${1/a_1} + {1/a_2}... + {1/a_{\phi(m)}}$ as a fraction $A_m / B_m$ in its lowest terms.
Generate some data for the value of $A_m (mod$ $m^2)$, try to find patterns, and then try to prove that the patterns you observe are true in general. In particular, when is $A_m = 0 (mod$ $m^2)$?

I proved earlier in the chapter that for all primes $p$ greater than 3, $A_p = 0 (mod$ $p^2)$, but it is also true for some composite integers, and I'm having trouble discerning a pattern. Thank you for any and all  help.

Comment: Can you share your data for, say $m\le5$, or whatever range you have covered?

Comment: For all $1 \leq m \leq 100$, $A_p=0 (mod$ $p^2)$ for m= 5,7,10,11,13,17,19,20,21,23,25,26,29,31,34,35,37,39,40,41,42, 
  43,47,49,50,52,53,55,57,58,59,61,63.65,67,68,70,71,73,74,77,78, 
79,80,82,83,84,85,89,91,93,95,97,100

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme%27s_theorem#Generalizations) on Wolstenholme's theorem contains the generalization that $A_m\equiv 0\mod{m^2}$ if $(m,6)=1$. Clearly this is not an if and only if, though.

Comment: Interesting, but is that generalization claiming that if (m,6)=1, the sum over the integers i s.t. (m,i)=1 of $1/i$ is an integer?

Comment: I found an OEIS sequence describing the terms, but it's not very helpful. http://oeis.org/A056818

Comment: I don't think it's claiming that the sum is integral; it earlier points out that such a congruence makes sense as long as the denominator is prime to the modulus.